# importing stylesheet with wp_enqueue_style() - wordpress not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Trying to import a custom **CSS** style sheet however it is not showing up in the inspect element and not working. **style.css** is inside a folder called **CSS** which is in the root directory. Any ideas?

**Functions.php**

```
<?php 
function learningWordPress_resources() {
        wp_enqueue_style('samirtheme-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
        // wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');

?>
```

**header.php**

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title> <?php bloginfo('name') ?> </title>

<?php/* allows wordpress to add whatever it needs to */wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: Cannot find it on `view page source` ? Code seems fine

Comment: The css is not even working though. Not showing in inspect element either

Comment: Did you check your `function.php` is called ? try to put some logs inside there and check if that works then check your hooks is called by WordPress

Comment: I am able to write html elements in functions.php that show up. Not sure what you mean by logs? New to wordpress, learning.

Comment: Okay then check add this line `die('my hooks called');`  as the first line of `learningWordPress_resources` then reload the page. If you see that my hooks called msg then your hook is working.
Do not try this on the production site.

Comment: I prefer to log status in my code or use `xdebug` so that I can check all codes are executed correctly.

Comment: ahh, i see. Yes i added the line in the function. It doesn't show up. So something is wrong with the hook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140217/discussion-between-thamaraiselvam-and-shaz).

Comment: click on the discussion link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) returns the web path to your current parent theme's folder. If you're not using a child theme, this is also your current themes's folder.

But if you are not a developer creating a theme that will be used by others, you should be using [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) which always returns the web path of your current theme folder (regardless of whether it's a child theme or not).

And, of course, you should place your custom style-sheet into

```
/wp-content/themes/{current_theme}/css/
```

If placing your style-sheet into a `/css` folder placed under root is important to you, use [get_site_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/).